# Article usage with "majority"

Tags: grammaticality, articles

What is the difference between "the majority of" "a majority of" and "majority of"? When do we use definite article with word "majority"?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the article (or absence thereof) doesn't tend to affect the meaning. Can you provide examples where you believe the article (or absence thereof) is affecting the meaning?

Comment: In this case pretty much either article works.  One might prefer one or the other in a particular context, but "rules" for that would be hard to define.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+majority%2C+the+majority&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20majority%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20majority%3B%2Cc0) shows us that a majority of "majority" users use "the majority".

Comment: (a) The majority of Elbonians are right-handed. (general statement) (b1) A majority of Elbonians go dextroboping at weekends (emphasising that this is one particular subset). (b2) A majority of 22 000 was achieved. (c) _

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I tried to tag you in a question about the word dextrobope :) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/560498/what-is-the-meaning-of-dextrobope

Answer (score 0):

*The majority of* is more correct than the others.

A majority is, by definition, 51% or more of something. So 55% and 73% are also majorities.

When you refer to a majority (I'm using *a* here because I'm discussing majorities of all kinds), you are referring to the fact that it is essentially **the** greater part of something. ***The*** means there is only one greater part, which is correct because there can't be two majorities of one thing.

Comment: Actually, a majority is anything greater than 50.0000...  And the only place where "the majority" is really mandated is when "majority" is being used as an adjective.